# Different token for CDATA section on purpose?

Tags: xml, go, cdata

Is there a special purpose for the extra token of the CDATA section in the following program?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    src := `<root>a<![CDATA[b]]>c</root>`
    r := strings.NewReader(src)

    dec := xml.NewDecoder(r)
    for {
        tok, err := dec.Token()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", tok)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/JRXUztgrfo

The output is

```
xml.StartElement{Name:xml.Name{Space:"", Local:"root"}, Attr:[]xml.Attr{}}
xml.CharData{0x61}
xml.CharData{0x62}
xml.CharData{0x63}
xml.EndElement{Name:xml.Name{Space:"", Local:"root"}}
EOF
```

but I would expect something like

```
xml.StartElement{Name:xml.Name{Space:"", Local:"root"}, Attr:[]xml.Attr{}}
xml.CharData{0x61, 0x62, 0x63}
xml.EndElement{Name:xml.Name{Space:"", Local:"root"}}
EOF
```

as the CDATA section should be transparent. Is there any reasoning on this?

The `a<![CDATA[b]]>c` should be equivalent to `abc` from the user's point of view.

Comment: CDATA is a node; if it were not it could not be created by the XML DOM; that is, it is *not* just an encoding detail. Not sure why it just comes in a text node (?) though, or maybe that is just the representation.. view the node type, perhaps.

Comment: @user2864740 [Not disagreeing with your point, just trying to understand the rationale behind the thing] Sure it is a node. But when I request the next token, I don't see any difference (as you write). So I'd expect it to be joined together, as from the user perspective (the program above doesn't see any information about that CDATA node) it is the same.

Comment: So your question is basically: "Why does Decoder Next work as documented (i.e. provide next token) instead of coalescing CDATA tokens and returning just one token for a sequence of CDATA tokens?"  Even the Streaming API for XML (StAX) does not coalesce these token in the default mode. Not sure what answer to give, it is just the way it works. What type of answer would you expect to see?

Comment: @Volker I don't know what type of answer I expect. Probably a technical answer in the form "the behaviour is on purpose, because of technical reason XYZ and the xml.CharData sections can't be joined together because ZYX". I do see the practical reasoning from the librarays programming point of view, but maybe there is some more behind that.

Comment: No, there is no deep technical reason. Joining the CDATA sections is trivial, the actual API is clean and straightforward and adding an option like `Coalescence bool` just makes the API complicated while giving very little extra value.